# Force Python in Pycharm, Mac, to use Discrete AMD GPU

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, gpu

Does anyone know how(e.g. libraries) to force Pycharm(Python) to use a discrete AMD GPU in a mac?

I'm using a 2016 Macbook Pro with Radeon 460, and I am in need to prime factorise this number, and I thought using the GPU would be faster:

8347879453436694939854738058201715370889272649572324043195256045640311690537183795264318225428212999500788633703142598940875581237513027689211142340762913

Many thanks!

Comment: Any other methods are welcome, but for those that thought of using wolfram alpha, it didn't work.